# How to name a server AWS::OpsWorks::Instance using CloudFormation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-opsworks

Anyone know how to give an "AWS::OpsWorks::Instance" a name? By default it is randomly getting the name of one of the layer types with a number appended (which I can't control), eg:

> db-master1
>
> or
>
> rails-app1

There is no property for the server name, nor does it inherit a name from the layers:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-opsworks-instance.html

Is there some alternative way to set the name - i'm using a CloudFormation JSON configuration to create an OpsWorks Rails stack.

Thanks

Comment: maybe you need raise a feature request to AWS directly.

Comment: oh right, do they have a formal process for that?

Comment: Check your account support level. Normally you pay support fee monthly, you should be fine to raise the support ticket directly to AWS. Otherwise, you have to discuss it in AWS owned forum.

Comment: I spoke with support. There was already an feature request on the cloud formation team to add OpsWorks instance hostname. It's now +1. Hopefully they will add it in the future. There is no work-around within just cloudformation unfortunately.